# How to achieve a smooth music transition with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I want to fade from one song to another on a web page. Here is a codepen that illustrates the issue:

[music transition test](http://codepen.io/littleredbowtie/pen/LpPaoW?editors=101)

I can achieve music volume fading with this code:

```
$("#mysong").animate({volume: 0}, 1000);
```

but the song switches before the fadeout is complete. I suspect this line

```
mysong.play();
```

is triggering the new song to play but if I omit that line, then the new song doesnt start up.

I tried this just before I change the source:

```
while (mysong.volume != 0)
```

but it has weird behavior. This first time you click the transition button, the music stops and eventually the next song fades in. Hitting the transition again only fades the volume and no longer changes the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animate method has a complete parameter that accepts a function. This function will be called after the animation is complete. Check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
$("#mysong").animate({volume: 0}, 1000, function() {
     //Your code here.
});
```

Comment: thank you. The concept of using a function as an argument to another function is not foreign to me I understand that the outer function would execute to completion before the the inner function started. An experienced coder like yourself might expect ONLY a callback to execute on completion of the outer function. But in a single threaded code, it's not clear to me why functions need to be nested just to wait for the preceding function to finish.I guess browsers will span threads as they see fit, turning linear code into mutliple asynchronous threads?

Comment: In fact, reading the documentation you pointed me to, I see that the animate function can also take another function as a 'promise' a function to call when the animation begins. However, it's not clear how you tell 'animate' if the function it is seeing should be a callback or a promise.

Comment: PS: The codepen was corrected. Interestingly, the line 'mysong.play() has to be in the call back as well.